# PHP handling the display of some calculations

Tags: php, if-statement, echo

I'm trying to calculate some things on a page, the testing echos work fine, but will not show up in the proper 'if' section. For some reason it keeps triggering the last else - huh? - section. I'm baffled after working in it for hours.

And yes, I'm kind of a newbie to php... I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing here.

```
<? $balance = number_format(($due - $paid), 2, '.', ''); ?>
<? echo $due; ?> - 
<? echo $paid; ?> = 
<? echo $balance; ?><br>
<? if (($balance = 0) AND ($paid = 0)) { ?>
    <a href="createworkorder.php?id=<?=$id?>&step=4" title="This ticket has no charges."><strong>$<?=number_format(($balance), 2, '.', ''); ?></a></strong>
<? } elseif ($balance > 0) { ?>
    <a href="createworkorder.php?id=<?=$id?>&step=4" title="Click to pay or print."><strong><font color="red">$<?=number_format(($balance), 2, '.', ''); ?></font></strong></a>
<? } elseif (($balance = 0) AND ($paid > 0)) { ?>
    <a href="createworkorder.php?id=<?=$id?>&step=4" title="PAID IN FULL. Ready to close"><strong><font color="lime">$<?=number_format(($balance), 2, '.', ''); ?></font></strong></a>
<? } else { ?>
    <a href="createworkorder.php?id=<?=$id?>&step=4" title="HUH??"><strong>$<?=number_format(($balance), 2, '.', ''); ?></a></strong>
<? } ?>
```

Comment: You're assigning instead of comparing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the assignment operator (`=`) where you should be using the comparison operator (`==`).

```
<? if (($balance = 0) AND ($paid = 0)) { ?>
```

should be

```
<? if (($balance == 0) AND ($paid == 0)) { ?>
```